# Emulator ok, Device fail, SecurityException: Permission Denial

Tags: android, manifest

I have to say that i'm using this android device for the first time, But I set USB debug.
It's like if it installed the app the first time and then it doesn't update any changes i do.

So, the app works on the Emulator.

I installed it on Xperia arc S (Sony Ericsson) device and it worked the first time.

Then i have chosen a different main activity in the manifest, and i got this error

```
ActivityManager: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: starting Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10000000 cmp=com.moob/.InitialMenuActivity } from null (pid=7195, uid=2000) requires null
```

But it still works on the emulator !! I already uninstalled the app on the mobile device but then the error above is raised.

Note that after uninstalling and starting again on the movile device, it re-installs the version that worked (I can start it manualy on the phone but it's the old version) before the manifest changes.

After erasing the app

```
Installing duelos_android.apk...
Success!
Starting activity com.moob.InitialMenuActivity on device 42583930325432573634
ActivityManager: Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=

[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=com.moob/.InitialMenuActivity }
ActivityManager: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: starting Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10000000 cmp=com.moob/.InitialMenuActivity } from null (pid=7195, uid=2000) requires null
```

The manifest -

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.moob"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <activity
            android:name=".SingleDuelActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".MultiDuelActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
        </activity>

         <activity
            android:name=".GameClientActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".LoadingActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >

        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".Ranking"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >

        </activity>  
         <activity
            android:name=".LogginActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >

        </activity>

         <activity
            android:name="com.moob.FB.FriendsList"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name="com.moob.FB.Example"            
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".InitialMenuActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:exported="true"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
             <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

        </activity>
    </application>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />

</manifest>
```

Here the LogCat

```
    11-19 12:32:42.506: D/AndroidRuntime(7718): >>>>>> AndroidRuntime START com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit <<<<<<
11-19 12:32:42.506: D/AndroidRuntime(7718): CheckJNI is OFF
11-19 12:32:42.506: D/dalvikvm(7718): creating instr width table
11-19 12:32:42.616: D/AndroidRuntime(7718): Calling main entry com.android.commands.pm.Pm
11-19 12:32:42.626: D/AndroidRuntime(7718): Shutting down VM
11-19 12:32:42.626: D/dalvikvm(7718): GC_CONCURRENT freed 101K, 71% free 299K/1024K, external 0K/0K, paused 1ms+1ms
11-19 12:32:42.626: D/dalvikvm(7718): Debugger has detached; object registry had 1 entries
11-19 12:32:42.626: I/AndroidRuntime(7718): NOTE: attach of thread 'Binder Thread #2' failed
11-19 12:32:42.746: D/AndroidRuntime(7728): >>>>>> AndroidRuntime START com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit <<<<<<
11-19 12:32:42.746: D/AndroidRuntime(7728): CheckJNI is OFF
11-19 12:32:42.746: D/dalvikvm(7728): creating instr width table
11-19 12:32:42.866: D/AndroidRuntime(7728): Calling main entry com.android.commands.am.Am
11-19 12:32:42.866: I/ActivityManager(262): Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10000000 cmp=com.moob/.InitialMenuActivity } from pid 7728
11-19 12:32:42.866: W/ActivityManager(262): Permission denied: checkComponentPermission() reqUid=10158
11-19 12:32:42.866: W/ActivityManager(262): Permission Denial: starting Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10000000 cmp=com.moob/.InitialMenuActivity } from null (pid=7728, uid=2000) requires null
```

InitialMenuActivty (I don't use clickUno and clickDos they are not from me)

```
public class InitialMenuActivity extends Activity {
private static final String TAG = "TESTING";

    //menu para ir a configuracion, jugar solo, ranking, puntuacion y multplayer
/*
 * 
 * 
 * http://greendao-orm.com/
 * 
 * 
 * */

    private SQLiteDatabase db;
    private DaoMaster daoMaster;
    private DaoSession daoSession;
    private LogroDao daoLogro;
    private Cursor cursor;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.mainmenu);




    }
    public void clickUno(View target)
    {
        Log.d(TAG, "click 1");  
        DevOpenHelper helper = new DaoMaster.DevOpenHelper(this, "notes-db", null);
        db = helper.getWritableDatabase();
        daoMaster = new DaoMaster(db);
        daoSession = daoMaster.newSession();
        daoLogro = daoSession.getLogroDao();
        final DateFormat df = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance(DateFormat.MEDIUM, DateFormat.MEDIUM);
        String comment = "logro en:" + df.format(new Date());
        daoLogro.insert(new Logro(null,comment,new Date()));
     /*   List<Logro> logros=daoLogro.queryBuilder().list();
        for (Iterator iterator = logros.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
            Logro logro = (Logro) iterator.next();
            Log.d(TAG, "Logro::"+logro.getLogro_name()+"-"+String.valueOf(logro.getDate()));
        }
        */



    }
    public void clickDos(View target)
    {
        Log.d(TAG, "click 2");
        List<Logro> logros=daoLogro.queryBuilder().list();
        for (Iterator iterator = logros.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
            Logro logro = (Logro) iterator.next();
            Log.d(TAG, "Logro::"+logro.getLogro_name()+"-"+String.valueOf(logro.getDate()));
        }

    }

    public void exempleFB(View target){

        Intent t = new Intent(InitialMenuActivity.this, Example.class);
        startActivity(t);
    }

    public void logginActivity(View target){

        Intent t = new Intent(InitialMenuActivity.this, LogginActivity.class);
        startActivity(t);
    }

    public void rankingActivity(View target){
        //if (Utility.arrayListFriend != null){
        Intent t = new Intent(InitialMenuActivity.this, Ranking.class);
        startActivity(t);
    }

    public void singleDuelActivity(View target){

        Intent t = new Intent(InitialMenuActivity.this, SingleDuelActivity.class);
        startActivity(t);
    }

    public void multiDuelActivity(View target){

    Intent t = new Intent(InitialMenuActivity.this, MultiDuelActivity.class);
    startActivity(t);
}
}
```

Comment: please share the full logcat stacktrace...

Comment: Did i add what you asked ? I took all messages from LogCat

Comment: Can you share the code from `InitialMenuActivity` class... it looks like there is some issue in one of the life cycle method in this class...

Comment: Have you tried without the line: android:exported="true" in your manifest file?

Comment: Yes I have, i added it checking other similar issues, but doesn't change anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, i had to clean the project and it solved the problem ... i still don't know why it was working on the emulator but not on the mobile device.

Answer (score 0):

I'm no expert myself, but since it seems like it's having trouble with Intents, why not try commenting out all the Intent sections you can.

I believe that Emulators typically don't have other apps that they can interact with (such as Facebook), so it could be that it was ignoring those intents, while your physical device is trying to process them.

Could do nothing, but worth a shot.